# Create multiple zip files

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, zip, 7-zip

I have a bunch of files that I would like to zip, I need a script to recursively run through a directory and find all files with name test*.txt as an example.

That is the easy part, so I have used 7zip to do this in powershell.

What I need now is to somehow limit the number of files per zip to 15 files.

So some restraints, this needs to be in .zip format and cannot be a spanned zip, my thinking for this is possibly to get powershell to run 15 at a time and then just sequentially create the zips, i.e. run first 15 as test.zip then next 15 as test1.zip and then next 15 as test2.zip etc.

Below is the code I am currently using.

```
if (-not (test-path "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {throw "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"} 
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe" 
$filename="test"
sz a -tzip -mx5 -mmt=on $Target\"$filename.zip" $Source\$filename*.txt -r
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with -- I make no promises or suggestions that this is the only/best method. Hopefully it gets you most of the way to where you want to be... :)

```
if (-not (test-path "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {
    throw "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"
} 

set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe" 

$filename="test"

# Get the list of files to zip  
$fileList = gci $Source\$filename*.txt

# Initalize a counter to keep track of which Zip we're working on.
$zipCounter = 1

# Loop through the file list, one at a time.
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $fileList.Length; $i++) {

    # Use the current entry in the File List array to add the file to the zip.
    sz a -tzip -mx5 -mmt=on "$target\$filename$zipCounter.zip" $fileList[$i] -r

    # Use modulus - if it returns no remainder, then the current loop is a multiple of 15. 
    # (+1 and putting it last in the loop make it consider the zip name for the NEXT loop.
    # I did this because "0 % 15 = 0"). 
    if (($i + 1) % 15 -eq 0) {
        # Multiple of 15? Time to switch to the next zip file.
        $zipCounter++
    }
}
```

Comment: All this was missing for me was to tell it to recurse when getting child items :)

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey Techie007, is there anyway that this could be limited by total size, I have now been thrown a curve ball where my zip file size has to be 4GB in size, I can get it to pull the size and give me the total but to loop through 4GB at a time is proving far to complex for my simple brain :)

Comment: What you're asking is complex, so the solution will be as well.  You'd have to collect all the files and their sizes, and then mix'n'match files of various sizes into groups that will compress to less than 4GB each. [Not a simple task](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), and well outside the scope of a single SU question, and REALLY out of scope for a the comments. ;)

Comment: I thought it may be a little more complex, thanks again for all the help. I do have sizes so will script it based on groups and just tweak the number of PST per zip. Thanks again

Comment: Hi, I'm pulling my hair out here, I have run into an issue that if the filename is the same in another folder it only keeps the single file. any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If there was a way to keep the folder structure in tact that would be ideal but I seem to lose the structure when running the loop